# htaccess http request re-routing

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**Reason for Problem:**
I'm working on a website and wanted to work on it without making edits to the live website. My hosting package allows for "infinite" domains. So instead of editing the live website I create a new domain, without purchasing the domain name and am trying to develop with this new domain.

**Issue At Hand:**
This issue is that the reference file paths don't work anymore and return 404 when trying to load the webpage. My original website directory structure looks like this

```
cgi-bin
config
public_html
    ->JSfiles
    ->CSSfiles
    ->PHPfiles
```

The new one is the same structure however when you open the "temporary web address" the URL looks like this

http://217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/"

instead of

http://myTempAddress.com/

so when my index.html file looks for /JSfiles/someJSfile.js its requesting

http://217.199.187.199/JSfiles/someJSfile.js

when it needs to be requesting

http://217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/JSfiles/someJSfile.js

**Things I've Tried Unsuccessfully:**
I would really like to fix this by redirecting with the .htaccess file in the root directory on the server. Ive tried using the following directives with no success.

```
Redirect /217.199.187.199/JSfiles/mustache.min.js http://217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/JSfiles/mustache.min.js
Redirect /JSfiles http://217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/JSfiles/
Redirect /JSfiles http://217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/
Redirect /JSfiles 217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/
```

**Question:**
How can I redirect the requests to the right location? I need all the the requests to be of the form http://217.199.187.199/myTempAddress.com/someDir/Somefile.ex

Comment: Questions about server configurations are off topic on SO and should be asked on serverfault.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up a bit more on Virtual Hosting in particular name based virtual hosting.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

It sounds like your provider might support name based VHosts but what you're trying to do is not taking advantage of that. To do what you want ie have path that points to a different version of your site is best achieved using mod_rewrite. See this

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

You need to make sure that your provided actually supports this.